# Text Becomes Prefixed in Command Line

Tags: command-line, terminal, putty

When using the up or down issue I sometimes get an issue where some of the previous commands text appears in front of my actually typing. It does not affect anything when I hit enter but it is very annoying having text appear at the beginning that appears to go with the rest. Any idea what is going wrong?

[image: command line]

Side info:
Connected using PuTTY on a Windows 7 machine, connecting to a Linux box.

Comment: What is the `[518]%`? Is that your [prompt])http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/unix/shellprompt.html) or is that some kind of progress indicator from a running program? What is your shell?

Comment: @terdon Tells how command number you are on, and you can check the history of your commands. I believe this is a Linux box (running Ubuntu).

Comment: @terdon My shell I guess is using bash? `6930 pts/29   00:00:00 bash`

Comment: Possibly the TERM environment variable is set incorrectly.

Comment: @Scott Must this be changed by a system admin, or can this be changed by myself from a normal ssh account?

Comment: If you have access to a shell, you can change it (unless the system admin has bent over backwards to prevent you).  Type `echo "$TERM"` and `echo "$term"` to see the current value.  I don’t know what it should be, and the syntax for changing it is different in different shells (e.g., `bash` vs. `csh` vs. `ksh`, etc. –– look at the `man` page for your shell) but a common one is `export TERM=ansi`, where “`ansi`” is a lowest-common-denominator setting that should work everywhere, but might not give you access to all the terminal’s capabilities.  (continued...)

Comment: (continued)  Check your PuTTY documentation to see whether it says what TERM should be set to –– it might be something obvious, like “`putty`”.